# MS Access Downloading Image From Table (URL)

Tags: database, image, vba, url, imageurl

I have been creating a database for my stock system and I have a column that has the image URL of each product. But I wish to have a vba module that downloads the images from the URLs from each row of the "Image_Url" column and save them in a folder. I have found a code for excel but I could not implement it on access.

Thanks for helps.

```
Option Explicit

Private Declare Function URLDownloadToFile Lib "urlmon" _
Alias "URLDownloadToFileA" (ByVal pCaller As Long, _
ByVal szURL As String, ByVal szFileName As String, _
ByVal dwReserved As Long, ByVal lpfnCB As Long) As Long

Dim Ret As Long

'~~> This is where the images will be saved. Change as applicable
Const FolderName As String = "C:\Temp\"

Sub Sample()
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim LastRow As Long, i As Long
Dim strPath As String

'~~> Name of the sheet which has the list
Set ws = Sheets("Sheet1")

LastRow = ws.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

For i = 2 To LastRow '<~~ 2 because row 1 has headers
    strPath = FolderName & ws.Range("A" & i).Value & ".jpg"

    Ret = URLDownloadToFile(0, ws.Range("B" & i).Value, strPath, 0, 0)

    If Ret = 0 Then
        ws.Range("C" & i).Value = "File successfully downloaded"
    Else
        ws.Range("C" & i).Value = "Unable to download the file"
    End If
Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: Hi Alper, welcome to SO. What went wrong when you adapt it to MSAccess? You must describe better.

Comment: Thank you! The problem is that, it says "objects required" when I use this code because it uses "activecell" which is an excel method. But I need the object to be taken from a specific column. Since I am so new to VBA and MS Access, I just cannot take the object (URLs) from each rows of that column.

Comment: 3 days, I am still searching.. :D